# I am running a maven project with package goal, it creates a .zip folder but no jar. Why is that?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, executable-jar

I am running a maven project with package goal, it creates a .zip folder but no jar. Why is that?

I am guessing I left a mistake in my pom.xml. Can somebody point it out?

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
         <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>swt1</groupId>
<artifactId>iMage</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
 <groupId>swt1.ub1.a1</groupId>
   <artifactId>2056751</artifactId>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
          <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
          <version>...choose your version...</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your packaging is set to pom, it should be jar see https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

```
<groupId>swt1.ub1.a1</groupId>
<artifactId>2056751</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

If on the other hand this is an aggregator project (a parent pom) you will need some modules and one of those may be your jar.

```
 <modules>
    <module>example-jar</module>
 </modules>
```

It depends what you want, if you want a jar and your src structure is suitable ask for a jar/

Comment: but in this case  'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging. What should I do then?

Comment: @ArminBeda see updated answer, you need to look at some example projects.